# Is this a bad way to implement a graph?

Tags: c++, graph

When I look at a book, I only show examples of how to implement graphs in almost every book by adjacent matrix method and adjacent list method.

I'm trying to create a node-based editor, in which case the number of edges that stretch out on each node is small, but there's a lot of vertex.

So I'm trying to implement the adjacent list method rather than the adjacent matrix method.
However, adjacent lists store and use each edge as a connection list.

But, I would like to use the node in the form listed below.

```
class GraphNode
{
    int x, y;
    dataType data;
    vector<GraphNode*> in;
    vector<GraphNode*> out;
public:
    GraphNode(var...) = 0;
};
```

So like this, I want to make the node act as a vertex and have access to other nodes that are connected.

Because when I create a node-based editor program, I have to access and process different nodes that are connected to each node.

I want to implement this without using a linked list.

And, I'm going to use graph algorithms in this state.

Is this a bad method?

Lastly, I apologize for my poor English.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. In particular, asking for "bad" is asking for an opinion. You need to define what you consider bad or good before that question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the point of the difference between adjacency list and adjacency matrix. The main point is the complexity of operations, like finding edges or iterating over them. If you compare a `std::list` and a `std::vector` as datatype implementing an adjacency list, both have a complexity of `O(n)` (`n` being the number of edges) for these operations, so they are equivalent.

Other considerations:

- If you're modifying the graph, insertion and deletion may be relevant as well. In that case, you may prefer a linked list.
- I said that the two are equivalent, but generally `std::vector` has a better locality of reference and less memory overhead, so it performs better. The general rule in C++ is to use `std::vector` for any sequential container, until profiling has shown that it is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It is probably a reasonable way for implementing a graph.

Long answer: What graph data structure to use is always dependent on what you want to use it for. A adjacency matrix is good for very dense graphs were it will not waste space due to many 0 entries and if we want to answer the question "Is there an edge between A and B?" fast. The iteration over all members of a node can take pretty long, since it has to look at a whole row and not just the neighbors.

An adjacency list is good for sparse graphs and if we mostly want to look up all neighbors of a node (which is very often the case for graph mustering algorithms). In a directed graph were we want to treat ingoing and outgoing edges seperately, it is probably a good idea to have a seperate adjacency list for ingoing and outgoing egdes (as has your code).

Regarding what container to use for the list, it depends on the use case. If you will much more often iterate over the graph and not so often delete something from it, using a vector over a list is a very good idea (basically all graph programms I ever wrote were of this type). If you have a graph that changes very often, you have to delete edges very often, you don't want to have iterator invalidation and so on, maybe it is better having a list. But that is very seldom the case.

A good design would be to make it very easy to change between list and vector so you can easily profile both and then use what is better for your program.

Btw if you often delete one edge, this is also pretty easily done fast with a vector, if you do not care about the order of your edges in adjacency list (so do not do this without thinking while iterating over the vector):

```
void delte_in_edge(size_t index) {
    std::swap(in[i], in.back());  // The element to be deleted is now at the last position, 
                                  // the formerly last element is at position i
    in.pop_back();                // Delete the current last element
}
```

This has O(1) complexity (and the swap is probably pretty fast).